# What to do with d3dx9math.h when converting to DirectX11?

Tags: c++, directx11, directx9

I'm converting an old game from DirectX9 to DirectX11 and I have a question: What I should use instead of `d3dx9math.h`?

Do I have to convert everything for `DirectXMath.h`(XNAMath), or I can continue with my old `d3dx9math.h` or even `d3dx10math.h`?

Comment: Converting to DirectXMath is the best long-term answer per [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxmath/pg-xnamath-migration-d3dx), but you can keep using D3DXmath (both d3dx9math and d3dx10math are the basically the same). You can also use [Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX) instead of the legacy DirectX SDK.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a math library, so as long as it doesn't interact with the actual D3D API, then you can in theory use any math library you wish.

Things to watch out for might include row-major vs column-major matrix conventions, -1..1 or 0..1 NDC Z conventions, etc, but otherwise choice of math library should be relatively constraint-free.